# What is a "prime implicent"?

Tags: logic

What is a "prime implicent"? I guess it's also the "prime implicant".

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicant#Prime_implicant) is too hard for me to understand. Can someone explain it in simpler terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ is an implicant of $f$ if $p\implies f$. It is a prime implicant if removing any variables from $p$ would result in the implication not being true anymore.

For example, $a\wedge b\implies b\wedge a$ but $a\not\implies b\wedge a$ and $b\not\implies b\wedge a$, therefore $a\wedge b$ is a prime implicant of $b\wedge a$.